# message size limit

Tags: ros, tcpros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In one of my nodes I get in a service call

```
a message of over a gigabyte was predicted in tcpros. that seems highly unlikely, so I'll assume protocol synchronization is lost.
```

In this case the msg is really 1+ Gig. Is is possible to increase the messages size limit temporary for this service call?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207786/message-size-limit/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2015-04-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-04-24**:
WTF? 1 Gigabyte? What are you transmitting there?

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-04-26**:
is kind of a map stitched from many images, sent once from the node that creates is to the node that uses it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message size limit in ROS is hardcoded. It should be possible to change it, but you'll need to modify roscpp and recompile it to do so.

A quick search on github turns up four locations that might be producing your error message: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=gigabyte

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-04-26**:
Thank you for the hint! I managed to compress the data before transferring it, which works around the issue as well....